# VPC EC2 Instances can PING each other, but not SSH

Tags: ssh, amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services, amazon-vpc

I've setup an SSH with multiple subnets.
I have an instance in my public subnet (Subnet A) built from an AWS NAT AMI. 
I have another instance in my private subnet (Subnet B) built from a standard Amazon Linux AMI.

I can SSH into the NAT instance in Subnet A from my local computer and can ping the regular instance in Subnet B from that NAT instance.
However, I cannot SSH into the regular instance from the NAT instance (connection times out).

I also provided temporary public access to the regular instance in Subnet B with an Elastic IP, then SSH'd into the regular instance. I was able to ping the NAT instance in Subnet A from Subnet B, but also could not SSH into the NAT instance from the regular instance.

SSH is running on both of the instance and the security groups are configured to accept SSH connections from anywhere.

It seems that the instances can ping each other, but nothing else. Whenever I SSH from one instance to the other I keep getting a connection timeout error.

Both instances are using the same keys. Subnet A is on 10.0.24.0/21 and Subnet B is on 10.0.0.0/21.
I feel like the solution should be somewhat simple, I'm just not seeing it.

Comment: What does your routing tables look like?

Comment: @Bazze Subnet A: 10.0.0.0/16 -> local, 0.0.0.0/0 -> <Internet Gateway> and Subnet B: 10.0.0.0/16 -> local, 0.0.0.0/0 -> <NAT instance>

Comment: I also confirmed that IP tables was not running on either instance.

Comment: Have you enabled outbound traffic SSH as well on the security groups?

Comment: Yep. The security group allows all outbound traffic. Testing the SSH from the NAT to another instance (this time with a public IP assigned to both instances) worked, but not with just a private IP on the instance and a public IP on the NAT.

Comment: When you create a VPC, Network Access control List (ACL) also created by default.
Did you check inbound/outbound in ACL?